# Manipulating two arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *web = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
NSMutableArray *disk = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
```

After comparing the two arrays I want to create one array called `remArray` that contains the objects that exist in disk array but not in web array (the string "1" in this case).

Then I want to create one array called `addArray` that contains the objects that exist in web array but not in disk array (the string "4" in this case).

Is there an easy way to do this without much overhead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better than NSArray, you could use [NSSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003736)

With NSMutableSet, you can remove object from an other set:

```
- (void)minusSet:(NSSet *)otherSet
```

The your code could be:

```
NSMutableSet *web = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
NSMutableSet *disk = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];

NSMutableSet * remArray = [[NSMutableSet setWithSet:disk] minusSet:web];
NSMutableSet * addArray = [[NSMutableSet setWithSet:web] minusSet:disk];
```

You can also read the [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) guide. Before using an array you have to determine if you want an ordered collection or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the removeObjectsInArray method:

```
NSMutableArray * remArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:disk];
[remArray removeObjectsInArray:web];
```

Do the same thing switching disk and web to get the addArray.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any really easy way, but rolling your "difference" method isn't too difficult.

Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
- (NSArray *) differnceBetween: (NSArray *) array1 and: (NSArray *) array2 {
    NSMutableArray *difference = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(id obj in array1) {
        if(![array2 contains:obj]) {
            [differnce addObject:obj];
        }
    }
    return difference;
}
```